# How do I set the scale of a BigDecimal stored procedure output param using Hibernate or Spring Data?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, jdbc, bigdecimal

Using JDBC, the scale can be set as follows:

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.DECIMAL, 34);
```

Per the javadoc, scale (in case 34) is the desired number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

How do I set the scale using Hibernate?

Using Hibernate, I don't see a way to specify the scale via its API:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("test")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
                        "aDecimal",
                        BigDecimal.class,
                        ParameterMode.OUT
                        ); //API has no scale parameter
```

Or annotations:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "blah.test", procedureName = "test", parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "aDecimal", type = BigDecimal.class), //No scale element here
```

**Update**

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and the stored procedure I'm calling on the DB server has an output parameter of type `DECIMAL(38,34)`.

Comment: Difficult to help you without specifying the Dialect (database...) you are using: some implementations of registerOutParameter(index, type, scale) just re-call registerOutParameter(index, type)... so scale is sometimes never used...

Comment: @p3consulting - Thanks for responding and letting me know. I've updated my OP. I'm using SQL Server 2019. I've tested and get 34 fractional digits when using the JDBC `registerOutParameter(4, Types.DECIMAL, 34)`. If I don't pass 34 as the last argument, I get 4 fractional digits just like when using Hibernate. Hibernate is clearly just using the default. I don't know how to tell Hibernate to get 34 fractional digits.

Comment: So you should trace the Hibernate calls up to the JDBC one hidden behind in order to see what happens with the parameter...

Comment: @p3consulting - I would have to presume that Hibernate would call `regsiterOutParameter(4, Type.DECIMAL)`. Since I don't know how to tell Hibernate to use a scale of 34, I don't see how it would call `regsiterOutParameter(4, Type.DECIMAL, 34)`. In other words, nothing is happening to the parameter in Hibernate b/c I don't know how to specify it to Hibernate. That's my question: "How do I specify it using JPA / Hibernate?"

Comment: If Hibernate doesn't pass the parameter to JDBC, I don't see what you can do. (Look at the source code of ProcedureParameterImpl.prepare(CallableStatement statement, int startIndex), the calls to registerOutParameter() use only the 2 first parameters)

Comment: @p3consulting - Right, that's what I'm trying to find out. I haven't been able to figure out how to specify the scale using the Hibernate API / Hibernate annotations. I was hoping that I was just overlooking a way to do this and someone else would know how. That's why I posted my question.

Comment: Since the `StoredProcedureParameter` annotation does not accept a scale, I guess this was just missed in the JPA spec. Hibernate also does not have a way to pass this through, but you can create a feature request for this by creating a JIRA issue.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov - Thanks for your response. I created a JIRA issue [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16041) on Jan 13, 2023.